I have a Flexbox wrap that has a small jump when the browser is scaled
I'm trying to achieve the following responsive behaviour when scaling the browser.
On desktop I want the label-input pair to show side by side. When scaling the browser width, I want the pairs to show on top of each other. Also the input and labels should be wrapped.
Here's some images of my structure and desired behaviour.
Desktop - Mobile
I'm close, using flexbox and wrap, however there are some small jumps when resizing:

I think it has something to do with the label and input pairs not being equal in size, but i thought the flex: 1 setting would make them equal.


.select-date-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.pair-left,
.pair-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pair>label {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.pair>input {
  flex: 2 2 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  /* Adjust spacing between elements as needed */
  max-height: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
}

#fetch_button {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
<div class="select-date-div">
  <div class="pair pair-left">
    <label id="start_date_label" for="start_date">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="text" id="start_date">
  </div>
  <div class="pair pair-right">
    <label id="end_date_label" for="end_date">End Date:</label>
    <input type="text" id="end_date">
  </div>
</div>




Have you tried to use CSS orientation?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation

Why is the jump troublesome?

Why wouldn't it be ?

Because (mobile) devices have a set of predefined dimensions? You think any of the devices actually has the dimension where the jump occurs?

The jump issue is because the label width of the "start date" and "end Date" is different, adjusting the label with the "start date" and "end Date" to be the same value should solve the issue.
https://plnkr.co/edit/reEwkDm50gow5J0X
.pair>label {
  width: 100px; // change flex to a fixed width of the label
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}


Thank you for your help :) It works for me when i set the width to 200px (100px overlaps with the input field). Since I'm new here I can't upvote yet, but it's much appreciated.

@rspct2allprogrammersworldwide it's ok, can you try to accept the answer by clicking the 'check' mark icon

Sure, thnxs again.
